# Open another form given a condition? C# visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm in form1 which name is "Suscripciones", and i want to call the form2 which name is "Suscripcion".
I'll show the code...

```
 DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("You want to add a new suscriptor?", "Suscripcion",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Form sus = new Suscripcion();
                    sus.Show();
                }
```

But that give me an error in Suscripciones();
The error message indicate: "no argument has been given that corresponds to the required formal parameter"
I don't know what to do, i can't call other form.

Comment: Does the constructor for `Suscripcion` have a parameter? Which line is giving you that error?

Comment: this error mostly occur when you receiving parameter in Suscription construction and you does pass argument from calling side. please verify it

Comment: No parameters. The error is when calls Suscripcion();
Line:
            Form sus = new Suscripcion();

Comment: It sounds like it does have a parameter. Can you show the code for the `Suscripcion` constructor?

Comment: Look in the code for the Suscripcion form for a line like this: public Suscripcion() If there is anything between the () then you need to provide that parameter, or get rid of whatever is between the (). There IS something between the parenthesis, or you would not get that error on that line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic way to pass arguments from one winform to another form.

**in form1 click event add**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 newform = new Form1();
    newform = this;
    this.Hide();
    MySecform = new Form2(ref newform);
    MySecform.Show();
}
```

**in form2 constructer**

```
public Form2(ref Form1 form1handel)
{
    firstformRef = form1handel;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

in form2 crate variable `Form1 firstformRef;`

```
private void Submitt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstformRef.TextBoxString = textBox1.Text;
    this.Close();
    firstformRef.Show();
}
```

Comment: I made edit to format properly the code. For your information, you can enclose any block of code with triple-backticks line : ```. This way, indentation and new lines are preserved. You can alsouse code  format in a line of normal text by using single backtick `